# Android Studio - can't run Android Device Manager

Tags: java, android, eclipse

When I try to run the Android Device Manager, and I get an error message pointing me to a log file. The errors refer to Eclipse libraries. I do have Eclipse installed. I've previously had difficulties With Android Studio when it was installed with Eclipse and a JDK previously installed. Then I uninstalled everything Java related, and reinstalled them, and then everything worked. I've tried that again in this case, but I'm still stuck. I'm running win7.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Here's the log file contents:

```
!SESSION 2018-02-19 17:16:13.694 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=9.0.4
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_GB
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -data @noDefault

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-02-19 17:16:14.350
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609/@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-02-19 17:16:14.381
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.jasper.glassfish_2.2.2.v201205150955.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-02-19 17:16:14.381
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.lucene.core_2.9.1.v201101211721.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-02-19 17:16:14.709
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.base_3.6.101.v201302041200.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-02-19 17:16:14.709
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.ui_3.5.201.v20130108-092756.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-02-19 17:16:14.709
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.webapp_3.6.101.v20130116-182509.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-02-19 17:16:14.724
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.jetty.server_8.1.3.v20120522.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-02-19 17:16:14.771
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.platform.doc.user_4.2.2.v20130121-200410.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-02-19 17:16:14.787
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.team.core_3.6.100.v20120524-0627.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-02-19 17:16:14.787
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.team.ui_3.6.201.v20130125-135424.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-02-19 17:16:14.802
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets_3.4.200.v20120521-2344.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-02-19 17:16:14.818
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.ui.intro_3.4.200.v20120521-2344.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 4 0 2018-02-19 17:16:14.958
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.8.0.v20120912-155025 [46]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: CDC-1.0/Foundation-1.0,J2SE-1.3
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1332)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1316)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.common 4 0 2018-02-19 17:16:14.958
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.100.v20120522-1841 [84]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: CDC-1.1/Foundation-1.1,J2SE-1.4
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1332)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1316)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-02-19 17:16:15.021
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.8.0.v20120912-155025.jar was not resolved.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-02-19 17:16:15.021
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.100.v20120522-1841.jar was not resolved.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-02-19 17:16:15.036
!MESSAGE Could not start bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.console
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not start bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.console
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.ConsoleManager.checkForConsoleBundle(ConsoleManager.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.0.0.v20120522-1841 [85]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: J2SE-1.5
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1332)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1316)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.ConsoleManager.checkForConsoleBundle(ConsoleManager.java:215)
    ... 10 more
Root exception:
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.0.0.v20120522-1841 [85]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: J2SE-1.5
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1332)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1316)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.ConsoleManager.checkForConsoleBundle(ConsoleManager.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2018-02-19 17:16:15.099
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2018-02-19 17:16:15.099
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director_2.2.0.v20120524-0542.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 2 0 2018-02-19 17:16:15.099
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4))(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.1)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2018-02-19 17:16:15.099
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer_3.2.0.v20120610-1946.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer 2 0 2018-02-19 17:16:15.099
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.1))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2018-02-19 17:16:15.099

etc - missing packages - 

!SUBENTRY 2 org.sat4j.pb 2 0 2018-02-19 17:16:15.192
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2018-02-19 17:16:15.192
!MESSAGE Bundle org.w3c.css.sac_1.3.1.v200903091627 [175] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.w3c.css.sac 2 0 2018-02-19 17:16:15.192
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3))(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2018-02-19 17:16:15.192
!MESSAGE Bundle org.w3c.dom.smil_1.0.0.v200806040011 [176] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.w3c.dom.smil 2 0 2018-02-19 17:16:15.192
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.w3c.dom_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.w3c.dom.smil 2 0 2018-02-19 17:16:15.192
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3))(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2018-02-19 17:16:15.192
!MESSAGE Bundle org.w3c.dom.svg_1.1.0.v201011041433 [177] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.w3c.dom.svg 2 0 2018-02-19 17:16:15.192
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.w3c.dom.smil_[1.0.0,1.1.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.w3c.dom.svg 2 0 2018-02-19 17:16:15.192
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.w3c.dom_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.w3c.dom.svg 2 0 2018-02-19 17:16:15.192
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3))(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0)))".

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-02-19 17:16:15.208
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```